# TypeORM: Unnecessary AND clause is added the final query while performing DELETE operation

Tags: postgresql, typescript, typeorm

`Edges` Table Structure:
`id | from_node | to_node`

Operation:

```
node.id = 1
await getManager().delete(Edge, [{ from_node: node.id }, { to_node: node.id }]);
```

Results in: the query

```
DELETE FROM "edges" WHERE (("from_node" = $1 AND "to_node" = $2) OR ("from_node" = $3 AND "to_node" = $4)) -- PARAMETERS: [1,null,null,1]
```

Whereas the query which I want is:

```
query: DELETE FROM "edges" WHERE ("from_node" = $1) OR ("to_node" = $2) -- PARAMETERS: [1,1]
```

I have no idea why the extra `AND` clause is being added to the resultant query.

On the other hand this code work perfectly fine:

```
getManger()
.createQueryBuilder()
.delete()
.from(Edge)
.where([{ from_node: node.id }, { to_node: node.id }])
.execute();
```

Can someone please explain the reason for mismatch in the actual and desired result in the `getManager().delete` operation?

DB: Postgres

Typeorm version: latest (0.2.24)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was happening because for `Edges` table the Primary Composite Key is `(from_node, to_node)`.